# Difference of connections $C^\infty(M)$-linear and the sum of connection and a $1$-form again a connection.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following proposition.

> IF $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ are two connections on a vector bundle $E$, then $\nabla-\nabla'$ is a $C^\infty(M)$-linear and can, therefore be considered as an element in $\mathcal{A}^1(M,\text{End}(E))$. If $\nabla$ is a connection on $E$ and $a \in \mathcal{A}^1(M,\text{End}(E))$, then $\nabla + a$ is again a connection on $E$.

I'm able to verify the linearity directly by the Leibniz rule. Given a smooth function $f$ and a section $s$ of $E$ I have

$$
(\nabla-\nabla')(fs)=(df\otimes s + f\nabla s) - (df\otimes s + f\nabla's)=f(\nabla-\nabla')(s).
$$

Now generally a connection is an element $\nabla \in \text{Hom}_{C^\infty(M)}(\Gamma(TM),\Gamma(T^*M \otimes E))$, but for some reason in this instance I should get the endomorphism bundle there.

Is there the tensor characterization lemma at play here in disguise? If so I would be glad to know how it is being used.

For the second statement I'm not sure how it makes sense to sum a connection and a $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form.

Comment: You can also think in terms of Christoffel symbols: when you subtract one connection from another, the derivative part goes away and you are left with the difference of two Christoffel symbols , i.e. a form with values in endomorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ${\rm End}(E)$-valued $1$-form is the same thing as a ${\rm C}^\infty(M)$-bilinear map $A:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E)$, taking $X$ and $\psi$ to a section $A_X\psi$. Now show that $$\nabla_X(f\psi) + A_X(f\psi) = f(\nabla_X\psi+A_X\psi) + X(f)\psi.$$The key point is that $A_X(f\psi)= fA_X\psi$ instead of $A_X(f\psi) = fA_X\psi + X(f)\psi$ (which only holds for a connection).

Comment: I don't yet understand how an ${\rm End}(E)$-valued $1$-form is the same as a ${\rm C}^\infty(M)$-bilinear map $A:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E)$. Wouldn't a map like $\Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(\text{End}(E))$ correspond to a $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form? @ivo-terek

Comment: @Tepes you can take a small detour: first, an $\text{End}(E)$-valued $1$-form can be defined as a bundle morphism $\alpha:TM\to\text{End}(E)$. This is equivalent by trivial linear algebra to a bilinear bundle morphism $\tilde{\alpha}:TM\oplus E\to E$. By a minor variant of the ‘tensor characterization lemma’, this is equivalent to a $C^{\infty}(M)$-bilinear map $A:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$, exactly as claimed here. The key is that $C^{\infty}(M)$-(multi)linearity allows you to go from the level of sections to the level of (multilinear) bundle morphisms.

Comment: Right this is exactly the same reason as to why the curvature tensor $R$ is a $\text{End}(E)$-valued $2$-form. Thanks, both of you. @peek-a-boo